# vis timeline is not visible

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I am trying to initialise a [visjs](https://visjs.org/) chart. I am using the testing data.

```
var container = document.querySelector('#chart')
var items = new vis.DataSet([
  {
    start: new Date(2010, 7, 15),
    end: new Date(2010, 8, 2),  // end is optional
    content: 'Test A'
  }
])
let options = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '200px',
 }
 this.timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options)
 console.log(this.timeline)
```

The chart seems to be intitalised but nothing is shown when rendering.
I have installed the module through npm, do I need to import the css too?

Comment: They should have called it `invis.js`.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to import the css too?

Yes, you can use a CDN link:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css
```

Or since you're using NPM, import from the source, eg, by using `vis/dist/vis.min.css`

---

Working demo:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#chart');
var items = new vis.DataSet([
    {
        start: new Date(2010, 7, 15),
        end: new Date(2010, 8, 2),  // end is optional
        content: 'Test A'
    }
]);

let options = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '200px'
}

this.timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js" rel="script"></script>


<div id="chart"></div>
```